# Dojo Data Grid Example Missing Styles & Infinite Scrolling

Tags: dojo

I just copied the code from [Dojo Website/Example about Data Grid](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html).

http://jsfiddle.net/6BtKk/

But as you can see, the styles appear to be missing. Also in the example site demo, theres infinite scrolling, what am I missing?

**UPDATE**: actually ... it appears like the demo site is having the same problem as mine now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid requires at least one more stylesheet:

```
dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css
```

If you are using a theme, there is another css that you need to add one of the following:

```
dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css
dojox/grid/resources/soriaGrid.css
dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css
```

An updated fiddle using the claro theme:

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/F8bDR/

By adding the styles, the scrolling begins displaying the rows.